# Gain of 0 dB for a common drain using JFET

Tags: amplifier, jfet, common-drain

I need to design a circuit that has a gain of 0 dB that allows a voltage attack on a 100 Ω load.

My first thought was to make a common-drain circuit since I had to use only JFETs. First I only used 1 JFET resulting in a gain of -3.6 dB. To increase it, I connected JFETs in parallel, 4 exactly, to have a "super transistor" which improved my gain to -1.26 dB, but I am still quite far from the result. I could've added more but I want this circuit to be makeable without too many struggles. I tried to modify every single resistance and even added some, but -1.26 dB was my best result. This was my circuit:

[image]

The specifications needed:

- Input impedance of at least 1 kΩ
- Max. output impedance of 10 Ω
- Gain of 0 dB, so replicate the input signal.
- Power supply of +/-12 V
- Input signal is 2 V amplitude sine wave with 200 Hz to 5 kHz frequency

Any ideas on how to improve this?

Here is the simulation:

[image]

PS: I know a 100 Ω load is ridiculous for a voltage attack because I will need an output impedance ≤ 10 Ω, but it is how it is.

Transient simulation at 2 kHz:

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use a current source?

Comment: Can you post the input and output waveforms?  I'm suspecting some distortion is being introduced.

Comment: Why don't you use a wire to connect your voltage source to the 100 ohm load. That has a gain of 0 dB within reason.

Comment: @TTiM3R I meant it as biasing instead of your resistor. But it doesn't matter, your transistor choice isn't good for what you want.

Comment: I don't see a spec for input impedance. One can get gain into a 100 ohm load by using a common-gate circuit - but input impedance must be quite low.

Comment: @glen_geek I added all the spec

Comment: What is a "voltage attack?"

Comment: @JRE it means that Rload >> Zout if you represent the system as a quadrupole

Answer (score 0):

How much swing are you expecting?

If somehow you want to go +/-11V (Otherwise I do not understand your supply voltage choice), then this is hopeless.

According to this datasheet (https://www.linearsystems.com/lsdata/datasheets/J111_SST111_Low_Noise_N-Channel_JFET_Switch.pdf), the min. IDSS of a J113 is 2mA.

If you want to go all the way to 11V, then you need to sink 110mA into your 100 ohm load (11V/100ohm). I don't think using ~55 units in parallel is a good idea for this.

You're going to need a device with a much bigger current handling capability if you want any gain close to 0dB at those swings.

Comment: No I want a swing of +-2V as I want to replicate my input signal which is a 2V amplitude sine wave with a frequency in the range of 200 to 5kHz.

Comment: @TTiM3R then why +/-12V as supply?

Comment: It is imposed for this project